# Juntar diversos arquivos PDF em um só

Tags: c#, html5, pdf

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para unir diversos pdfs em um, consegui fazer através de dois uploads, porém, gostaria de em um upload poder selecionar vários e unificar os pdfs. Alguém poderia me ajudar? Segue abaixo o código já feito:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="file1" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"></asp:FileUpload>
<asp:FileUpload ID="file2" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"></asp:FileUpload>


  protected void Merge(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (file1.HasFile && file2.HasFile)
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader1 = new PdfReader(file1.PostedFile.InputStream);
        PdfReader pdfReader2 = new PdfReader(file2.PostedFile.InputStream);

        List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();
        readerList.Add(pdfReader1);
        readerList.Add(pdfReader2);


        //Define a new output document and its size, type
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        //Get instance response output stream to write output file.
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
        document.Open();

        foreach (PdfReader reader in readerList)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
            {
                PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
                document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
            }
        }
        document.Close();

        Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=OutPut.pdf");
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    }

}
```

Comment: Não entendi, você consegue fazer com dois, mas não consegue fazer com N?

Comment: exatamente, eu consigo unir dois arquivos de pdfs através de 2 uploads. A ideia seria em apenas 1 upload file, eu conseguir selecionar diversos pdfs e unificá-los em um.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça uma iteração entre os arquivos postados e adicione eles a sua lista, embora você permita que cada input receba vários arquivos acho que o que faria mais sentido seria deixar apenas um field com seleção múltipla ou `N` com a seleção simples. Mas no exemplo abaixo, vai funcionar em ambos casos.

```
protected void Merge(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var postFiles = Request.Files as HttpFileCollection;

    List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();

    for (int key = 0; key < postFiles.Count; key++)
    {
        var arquivo = postFiles[key] as HttpPostedFile;
        var pdf = new PdfReader(arquivo.InputStream);
        readerList.Add(pdf);
    }

    //Define a new output document and its size, type
    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    //Get instance response output stream to write output file.
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
    document.Open();

    foreach (PdfReader reader in readerList)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
        {
            PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
            document.Add(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(page));
        }
    }
    document.Close();

    Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=OutPut.pdf");
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

    }
}
```

Comment: Funcionou!! dei uma adaptada aqui e ficou certinho! Obrigado!!

Answer (score 0):

O que está a faltar no seu código é obter os múltiplos ficheiros selecionados no `FileUpload`. A propriedade `AllowMultiple="true"` está bem atribuída mas não está a tirar partido disso.

O objetivo passa por utilizar apenas um `FileUpload` e selecionar todos os PDF lá, depois tratar isso em código:

### HTML

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="files" runat="server" AllowMultiple="true"></asp:FileUpload>
```

### C#

```
protected void Merge(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection postedFiles = Request.Files;
    List<PdfReader> readerList = new List<PdfReader>();

    foreach(HttpPostedFile postedFile in postedFiles)
        readerList.Add(new PdfReader(postedFile.InputStream));

    // ... resto do código
}
```